# I can't connect in MySQL data base WildFly - Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I want to make a simple CRUD with JSF, i'm using WildFly 9.0.2 Server.
I already make the standalone.xml and modules.xml configurations, but i still have the errors bellow :

```txt
WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000299: Could not complete schema update: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/
ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/
```

The stack is too large to input here.

Datasources part of standalone.xml:

```xml
<datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/SiscosearchDS" pool-name="siscosearch" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/siscosearch/</connection-url>                 
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>admin</password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

And Persistence.XML :

```
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE_UNIT" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/SiscosearchDS</jta-data-source>

<properties>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Anyone can help me ? 
I tryed everything.

Comment: can you share your persistence.xml and datasource part of your standalone.xml

Comment: @xxlali I update the post. Do you need another details ?

Comment: I am not %100 sure. This is just advice. Follow https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Example_MySQL_XA_Datasource1.html this url to create your datasouce.

Comment: The standalone.xml looks good. However, it references to module `com.mysql` in the _drivers_ part. Did you install the mysql driver as your module name `com.mysql`? If yes, can you show the module.xml file? If the installation is not done yet, this post might help: [Install Mysql JDBC Driver on WildFly 8.2](http://giordanomaestro.blogspot.tw/2015/02/install-jdbc-driver-on-wildfly.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up using WildFly, is very powerfull and fast, but so hard to configure..
Now i'm using TomCat 9 on my project and work perfectly.

Thanks guys, for your contributions !